# Redirect comment permalink to their corresponding node paths

Tags: 7, redirection

Is there any way in drupal to  redirect comment permalink to their corresponding node paths or url alias?

I want to redirect all comment/x paths to their corresponding node-path. And it should handle pagers as well. If your comment is in the second page (when you have set a comments-per-page value in node type settings), it should be like

http://example.com/comment/111 to http://example.com/node/123?page=1#comment-111

```
http://example.com/comment/111 to http://example.com/node/123#comment-111
http://example.com/comment/112 to http://example.com/node/123#comment-112
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It can be done programmatically I think. By using `hook_preprocess_page`.

Comment: @SumitMadan Thanks for ur comment. But I somehow managed to acheive it through hook_menu_alter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to acheive it through hook_menu_alter. It just works great for me

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_menu_alter.
* @author Md Eqbal Ahmad <*****@******.com>
*/
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['comment/%']['page callback'] = 'MODULE_commentpermalink';
}

/**
 * Redirect comment permalink to their corresponding node paths
 * @author Md Eqbal Ahmad <*****@*****.com>
*/
function MODULE_commentpermalink($cid) {
  if (($comment = comment_load($cid)) && ($node = node_load($comment->nid))) {
    // Find the current display page for this comment.
    $page = comment_get_display_page($comment->cid, $node->type);
    // Now, rather than setting menu_executive_active_handler and changin $_GET valies, we redirect them to the actual node URL with fragments and pager set.
    if ($page > 0) {
      drupal_goto("node/$comment->nid", array('fragment'=>"comment-$comment->cid",'query'=>array('page'=>$page)), 301);
    }
    else{
      drupal_goto("node/$comment->nid", array('fragment'=>"comment-$comment->cid"), 301);
    }
  }
  drupal_not_found();
}

?>
```

Comment: I thinks, this is not a right way to do. `hook_page_process` is more better way than this. `hook_menu_alter` means you are altering the page content.

Comment: @SumitMadan I will be highly obliged, if possible, if u provide a code snippet  using hook_page_process to redirect comment permalink to their corresponding node paths as ur Answer to the question

Comment: checkout my answer.

Comment: @SumitMadan Thanks for ur answers! I have a question that dont u think redirection at hook_page_process has a slow page loading issue. The bulk content array is generated and then u are opting for redirection to load the same page content.

Comment: I dont think so. I never found any issue with this option.

Comment: @SumitMadan Conceptually I find `hook_menu_alter` a better stage to redirect rather than at `hook_process_page` or a similar approach could be at `hook_init`. But I really appreciate ur valuable comment . Its really nice intracting with u.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using `hook_preprocess_page` :

```
function MODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      if (arg(0) == 'comment') {
        $cid = arg(1);
        if (($comment = comment_load($cid)) && ($node = node_load($comment->nid))) {
          // Find the current display page for this comment.
          $page = comment_get_display_page($comment->cid, $node->type);
          // Now, rather than setting menu_executive_active_handler and changin $_GET valies, we redirect them to the actual node URL with fragments and pager set.
          if ($page > 0) {
            drupal_goto("node/$comment->nid", array('fragment'=>"comment-$comment->cid",'query'=>array('page'=>$page)), 301);
          }
          else{
            drupal_goto("node/$comment->nid", array('fragment'=>"comment-$comment->cid"), 301);
          }
        }
        drupal_not_found();
      }
    }
```